# Not Getting Twitter Highlights/Recommendations on iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, notifications, twitter

I have two Twitter accounts. Account #2 "recommends" tweets via in-app/push notifications and sends "highlights" push notifications but my Primary account only sends recommendation notifications (no highlights) but they don't show up in-app. All other notifications work well for both accounts on both iPhone and iPad.

I have both features turned on in "Push Notifications" settings on both iPhone and iPad. I've had this issue for months, it hasn't resolved itself. I've read the articles about both features on Twitter's website but they don't offer much trouble-shooting. No response from Twitter support.

Do I need to erase my login info from both devices, delete both apps, and start over again or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter is [A/B Testing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) this feature between accounts. It's possible only one of your accounts is part of the active test group for this experiment. There's nothing you can do to change this currently.

Comment: I agree that in-app notifications for recommendations could not be rolled out to everyone but what makes you conclude that Highlights aren't fully rolled out? The [support page](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20172643) makes no mention of that and I haven't seen it anywhere on the web.